# Printing a struct using description

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, struct, nslog

I would like to know if it is possible to use the `description` function in the Cocoa framework to log the contents of a `struct`. For example:

```
    typedef struct {float a,b,c;}list;
    list testlist = {1.0,2.5,3.9};
    NSLog(@"%@",testlist); //--> 1.0,2.5,3.9
```

Comment: So far as I know, nope.  Has to be an Objective-C object for `description` to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The `description` message is a method found in the `NSObject` protocol, so by definition, must be an object.  There is, however, a more convenient way of log debugging, using a `LOG_EXPR()` macro.  This will take objects and structs:

`LOG_EXPR(testlist);`

Which would output:

> testlist = {1.0, 2.5, 3.9};

This code can be found [here](http://vgable.com/blog/2010/08/19/the-most-useful-objective-c-code-ive-ever-written/).

Answer (score 1):

`description` is a method and as such can only be called on an object. In turn, the `%@` format specifier only works for objects which respond to `description`.

You can write your own function to make a pretty `NSString` with the contents of your struct:

```
NSString * pretty_string_from_list( list l ){

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<list: [%f, %f, %f]>", l.a, l.b, l.c];
}
```

Then call that function when you log the struct:

```
NSLog(@"%@", pretty_string_from_list(testlist));
```